# Extending the sides of my nav bar in CSS/HTML (just like the header)

Tags: html, css, extend, navbar, edges

I have been searching since yesterday for a solution but couldn't find one, or couldn't find the right keywords to search with.

So I have a header on my website like this is a header and I centered that nicely and extended the background color of it.

Now I found out how to make a nice interactive/glossy nav bar as a footer but im using it at the top and the thing is I also want to extend it's size, however it just centers itself and doesn't extend. I'll show this in a screenshot and will post my code.

Also: I want my  box to be centered, which is contained in a div called #main_inner_area.

**Note: Navbar is still called #footer in CSS/HTML code.. I want to extend the sides of my navbar, like the background color of my header is extended to the full width.**
 my screenshot: i41 DOT tinypic DOT com SLASH 2qk6mmt.png (sorry but its hard to explain without screenie)

HTML:

```
<div id="main_area">
    <header> 
     <h1>This is a header</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="footer">long code for layout navbar</div>

    <div id="main_inner_area">
        <article>d       fsdf sdf sdf dsf dsf dsf</article>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
#main_area{
    background:#4863A0;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;


}
header {

height:100px;
background: #4863A0;
color:white;
border:none;
width:700px;
margin: 0 auto;


}



#footer{

    width:700px;
            top:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;

            margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
            border-radius:7px 7px 7px 7px;
    font-family:Arial;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black; /*h,v,blur,color */
    /* glass effect */
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    /*inset = inner shadow ----------- this just creates multiple shadows*/
    /*top border, top white section, overlay top white, bottom*/
    box-shadow:  inset 0px -2px rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
         inset 0px -15px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
         inset 0 -10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25),
         inset 0 15px 30px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
}

#main_inner_area{
            float: left;
            width:735px;
            margin:25px 0px 10px 0px; 

}

article{

        background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
        border: 1px solid #4863A0;
        margin:0px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align:left;
        display:block;
        width:700px;
        height:auto;
        border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;     

}
```

P.S. I'd REALLY appreciate it. Im an 18 year old student trying to learn some extra things next to my study.

Comment: What exactly do you want to extend in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your header dynamic just remove the `width` attribute from it (and from #footer aswell). If you set it to a fixed value of course it cannot scale.

To center your `article` use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

**Update:** (stretch Nav Bar)

CSS Changes

```
#footer {
    width: auto;
}

#footer .links {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML Changes:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="links">long code for layout navbar</div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/UKYDb/1/

Comment: The header is fine as it is, i used margin: 0 auto; for that. The header is centered nicely and the background color of it extends nicely. I just want that also with the #footer element (which is my nav bar now.)

Comment: @user1842140 your nav bar is centered for me. I don't quite understand what your issue is. To center the article you have to make the container big enough so it actually can be centered relatively. So set `width: 100%;` in `#main_inner_area`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/UKYDb/

Comment: The centering worked now. Is there any way u can make the nav bar extend to the full width WITHOUT stretching the buttons as well to left and right hand side of the screen?

Comment: @user1842140 To stretch the nav bar like that you have to give it a full width (remove the width attribute or `width: auto;`) and store the content in a child element with a width of 700px; See updated answer for code.

Comment: id give u +rep but I cant :( (dont have enough)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "extend" but you're setting a fixed width and height to everything:

```
#footer {
width: 700px;
height: 40px;
...
}
```

Try using percents instead of fixed widths for everything in your CSS code.

```
width: 100%;
```

Comment: with extending I mean that my nav bar stays centered on my page. And the sides of it do not extend to the full width of the screen. width100% just makes the nav bar start at the very left of the screen and stretches to the right. I want my buttons to stay in the center..

Comment: Are you using `text-align: center;` ?